# git-svn rebase error

Tags: git, version-control, git-svn

I am getting the following error after running git svn rebase: 'update-index --refresh: command returned error: 1'

Any ideas?  Below is the entire output.

```
$ git svn rebase --dry-run
xxx-iphone/xxx_prototype2/xxx_prototype2.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: needs update
xxx-iphone/xxx_prototype2/xxx_prototype2.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/xxx.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate: needs update
xxx-iphone/xxx/xxx_prototype2/CouponBookViewController.h: needs update
xxx-iphone/xxx_prototype2/xxx_prototype2/CouponBookViewController.m: needs update
xxx-iphone/xxx_prototype2/xxx_prototype2/EmailListViewController.m: needs update
xxx-iphone/xxx_prototype2/xxx_prototype2/HomeViewController.h: needs update
xxx-iphone/xxx_prototype2/xxx_prototype2/ParentCategoryTableViewCell.xib: needs update
xxx-rails/.rvmrc: needs update
xxx-rails/Gemfile: needs update
xxx-rails/app/controllers/admin_page/categories_controller.rb: needs update
xxx-rails/app/controllers/application_controller.rb: needs update
xxx-rails/app/controllers/categories_controller.rb: needs update
xxx-rails/app/controllers/service_provider_profiles_controller.rb: needs update
xxx-rails/app/models/category.rb: needs update
xxx-rails/app/models/like.rb: needs update
xxx-rails/app/models/service_provider_profile.rb: needs update
xxx-rails/config/application.rb: needs update
xxx-rails/db/development.sqlite3: needs update
update-index --refresh: command returned error: 1
```

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out.  I needed to add the updated files (git add -u) and commit before running 'git svn rebase'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the updated files (`git add -u`) and commit before running `git svn rebase`.